# Ruby version 2.2.5 but your Gem file specified 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I already tried to update gem bundle and also try to pick gem 2.1.2 but ruby is not supporting them. Here is the error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OX3u.jpg)

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'bcrypt', require: 'bcrypt'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip'

group :development, :test do
 gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'binding_of_caller'
 gem 'better_errors'
 gem 'annotate'
 gem 'dotenv-rails'
 gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have defined the ruby version for your project in the Gemfile. If you comment it out then, your app could use the system version of Ruby. If you need further help please publish the code in Gemfile.